# Need a simple one-liner to highlight an entire row based on if that row contains 'text' (case insensitive)

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Tons of examples online, and they're close, but none are concisely a solution to the problem.

I would like a simple one-liner to use in the Conditional Format sidebar that highlights a row if it contains 'text' in any of the row cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(A1:Z),,999^99))),"text","♠"), "♠"))="♠",1,))=1,1)
```

[image: 0]